# SQLite triggers & datetime defaults in SQL DDL using Peewee in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have a SQLite table defined like so:

```
create table if not exists KeyValuePair (
    key         CHAR(255) primary key not null,
    val         text not null,
    fup         timestamp default current_timestamp not null,  -- time of first upload
    lup         timestamp default current_timestamp not null  -- time of last upload
);

create trigger if not exists entry_first_insert after insert
on KeyValuePair
begin
    update KeyValuePair set lup = current_timestamp where key = new.key;
end;

create trigger if not exists entry_last_updated after update of value
on KeyValuePair
begin
    update KeyValuePair set lup = current_timestamp where key = old.key;
end;
```

I'm trying to write a `peewee.Model` for this table in Python. This is what I have so far:

```
import peewee as pw


db = pw.SqliteDatabase('dhm.db')
class BaseModel(pw.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class KeyValuePair(BaseModel):
    key = pw.FixedCharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    val = pw.TextField(null=False)
    fup = pw.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='first_updated', null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    lup = pw.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name='last_updated', null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)

db.connect()
db.create_tables([KeyValuePair])
```

When I inspect the SQL produced by the last line I get:

```
CREATE TABLE "keyvaluepair" (
    "key" CHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "val" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "fup" DATETIME NOT NULL,
    "lup" DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

So I have two questions at this point:

1. I've been unable to find a way to achieve the behavior of the `entry_first_insert` and `entry_last_updated` triggers. Does `peewee` support triggers? If not, is there a way to just create a table from a .sql file rather than the `Model` class definition?
2. Is there a way to make the default for `fup` and `lup` propogate to the SQL definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out a proper answer to both questions. This solution actually enforces the desired triggers and default timestamps in the SQL DDL.

First we define a convenience class to wrap up the SQL for a trigger. There is a more proper way to do this with the `peewee.Node` objects, but I didn't have time to delve into all of that for this project. This `Trigger` class simply provides string formatting to output proper sql for trigger creation.

```
class Trigger(object):
    """Trigger template wrapper for use with peewee ORM."""

    _template = """
    {create} {name} {when} {trigger_op}
    on {tablename}
    begin
        {op} {tablename} {sql} where {pk} = {old_new}.{pk};
    end;
    """

    def __init__(self, table, name, when, trigger_op, op, sql, safe=True):
        self.create = 'create trigger' + (' if not exists' if safe else '')
        self.tablename = table._meta.name
        self.pk = table._meta.primary_key.name
        self.name = name
        self.when = when
        self.trigger_op = trigger_op
        self.op = op
        self.sql = sql
        self.old_new = 'new' if trigger_op.lower() == 'insert' else 'old'

    def __str__(self):
        return self._template.format(**self.__dict__)
```

Next we define a class `TriggerTable` that inherits from the `BaseModel`. This class overrides the default `create_table` to follow table creation with trigger creation. If any triggers fail to create, the whole create is rolled back.

```
class TriggerTable(BaseModel):
    """Table with triggers."""

    @classmethod
    def triggers(cls):
        """Return an iterable of `Trigger` objects to create upon table creation."""
        return tuple()

    @classmethod
    def new_trigger(cls, name, when, trigger_op, op, sql):
        """Create a new trigger for this class's table."""
        return Trigger(cls, name, when, trigger_op, op, sql)

    @classmethod
    def create_table(cls, fail_silently=False):
        """Create this table in the underlying database."""
        super(TriggerTable, cls).create_table(fail_silently)
        for trigger in cls.triggers():
            try:
                cls._meta.database.execute_sql(str(trigger))
            except:
                cls._meta.database.drop_table(cls, fail_silently)
                raise
```

The next step is to create a class `BetterDateTimeField`. This `Field` object overrides the default `__ddl__` to append a "DEFAULT current_timestamp" string if the `default` instance variable is set to the `datetime.datetime.now` function. There are certainly better ways to do this, but this one captures the basic use case.

```
class BetterDateTimeField(pw.DateTimeField):
    """Propogate defaults to database layer."""

    def __ddl__(self, column_type):
        """Return a list of Node instances that defines the column."""
        ddl = super(BetterDateTimeField, self).__ddl__(column_type)
        if self.default == datetime.datetime.now:
            ddl.append(pw.SQL('DEFAULT current_timestamp'))
        return ddl
```

Finally, we define the new and improved `KeyValuePair` Model, incorporating our trigger and datetime field improvements. We conclude the Python code by creating the table.

```
class KeyValuePair(TriggerTable):
    """DurableHashMap entries are key-value pairs."""

    key = pw.FixedCharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    val = pw.TextField(null=False)
    fup = BetterDateTimeField(
        verbose_name='first_updated', null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    lup = BetterDateTimeField(
        verbose_name='last_updated', null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)

    @classmethod
    def triggers(cls):
        return (
            cls.new_trigger(
                'kvp_first_insert', 'after', 'insert', 'update',
                'set lup = current_timestamp'),
            cls.new_trigger(
                'kvp_last_udpated', 'after', 'update', 'update',
                'set lup = current_timestamp')
        )

KeyValuePair.create_table()
```

Now the schema is created properly:

```
sqlite> .schema keyvaluepair
CREATE TABLE "keyvaluepair" ("key" CHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "val" TEXT NOT NULL, "fup" DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp, "lup" DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp);
CREATE TRIGGER kvp_first_insert after insert
    on keyvaluepair
    begin
        update keyvaluepair set lup = current_timestamp where key = new.key;
    end;
CREATE TRIGGER kvp_last_udpated after update
    on keyvaluepair
    begin
        update keyvaluepair set lup = current_timestamp where key = old.key;
    end;
sqlite> insert into keyvaluepair (key, val) values ('test', 'test-value');
sqlite> select * from keyvaluepair;
test|test-value|2015-12-07 21:58:05|2015-12-07 21:58:05
sqlite> update keyvaluepair set val = 'test-value-two' where key = 'test';
sqlite> select * from keyvaluepair;
test|test-value-two|2015-12-07 21:58:05|2015-12-07 21:58:22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the save function of the model where you insert the timestamps. See [TimeStampModel](https://blog.muya.co.ke/timestamped-model-in-peewee/) for an example.

Comment: This only enforces the desired behavior at the application level. The underlying database is still prone to corruption if another application makes updates.

Comment: Yes that's true. But the option you want is not out of the box available for peewee. You should alter the database yourself after creation of the tables.

Comment: You can use `SQL (" NOW () ")` as value when saving

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across exactly this issue a while ago, and spent some time coming up with an optimal design to support Triggers in PeeWee (inspired by the above answer). I am quite happy with how we ended up implementing it, and wanted to share this. At some point I will do a PR into Peewee for this.

## Creating Triggers & TriggerListeners in PeeWee

### Objective

This document describes how to do this in two parts:

- How to add a `Trigger` to a model in the database.
- How to create a `ListenThread` that will have a callback function that is notified each time the table is updated.

### How-To Implementation

The beauty of this design is you only need one item: the TriggerModelMixin Model. Then it is easy to create listeners to subscribe/have callback methods.

The TriggerModelMixin can be copy-pasted as:

```
class TriggerModelMixin(Model):
    """ PeeWee Model with support for triggers.
    This will create a trigger that on all table updates will send
    a NOTIFY to {tablename}_updates.
    Note that it will also take care of updating the triggers as
    appropriate/necesary.
    """

    _template = """
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION {function_name}()
        RETURNS trigger AS
        $BODY$
        BEGIN
          PERFORM pg_notify(
            CAST('{notify_channel_name}' AS text),
            row_to_json(NEW)::text);
          RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $BODY$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
        COST 100;
        ALTER FUNCTION {function_name}() OWNER TO postgres;

    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS {trigger_name} ON "{tablename}";

    CREATE TRIGGER {trigger_name}
        AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
        ON "{tablename}"
        {frequency}
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE {function_name}();
    """

    function_name_template = "{table_name}updatesfunction"
    trigger_name_template = "{table_name}updatestrigger"
    notify_channel_name_template = "{table_name}updates"
    frequency = "FOR EACH ROW"

    @classmethod
    def get_notify_channel(cls):
        table_name = cls._meta.table_name
        return cls.notify_channel_name_template.format(**{"table_name": table_name})

    @classmethod
    def create_table(cls, fail_silently=False):
        """ Create table and triggers """
        super(TriggerModelMixin, cls).create_table()

        table_name = cls._meta.table_name
        notify_channel = cls.get_notify_channel()
        function_name = cls.function_name_template.format(**{"table_name": table_name})
        trigger_name = cls.trigger_name_template.format(**{"table_name": table_name})

        trigger = cls._template.format(**{
                                            "function_name": function_name,
                                            "trigger_name": trigger_name,
                                            "notify_channel_name": notify_channel,
                                            "tablename": table_name,
                                            "frequency": cls.frequency
                                         }
                                       )
        logger.info(f"Creating Triggers for {cls}")
        cls._meta.database.execute_sql(str(trigger))

    @classmethod
    def create_db_listener(cls):
        ''' Returns an object that will listen to the database notify channel
        and call a specified callback function if triggered.
        '''

        class Trigger_Listener:
            def __init__(self, db_model):
                self.db_model = db_model
                self.running = True
                self.test_mode = False
                self.channel_name = ""

            def stop(self):
                self.running = False

            def listen_and_call(self, f, *args, timeout: int = 5, sync=False):
                ''' Start listening and call the callback method `f` if a
                trigger notify is received.
                This has two styles: sync (blocking) and async (non-blocking)
                Note that `f` must have `record` as a keyword parameter - this
                will be the record that sent the notification.
                '''
                if sync:
                    return self.listen_and_call_sync(f, *args, timeout=timeout)
                else:
                    t = threading.Thread(
                        target=self.listen_and_call_sync,
                        args=(f, *args),
                        kwargs={'timeout': timeout}
                    )
                    t.start()

            def listen_and_call_sync(self, f, *args, timeout: int = 5):
                ''' Call callback function `f` when the channel is notified. '''
                self.channel_name = self.db_model.get_notify_channel()
                db = self.db_model._meta.database

                db.execute_sql(f"LISTEN {self.channel_name};")
                conn = db.connection()
                while self.running:
                    # The if see's if the response is non-null
                    if not select.select([conn], [], [], timeout) == ([], [], []):
                        # Wait for the bytes to become fully available in the buffer
                        conn.poll()
                        while conn.notifies:
                            record = conn.notifies.pop(0)
                            logger.info(f"Trigger recieved with record {record}")
                            f(*args, record=record)
                    if self.test_mode:
                        break

        return Trigger_Listener(cls)
```

Example Implementation:

```
db_listener = FPGExchangeOrder.create_db_listener()

def callback_method(record=None):
     # CallBack Method to handle the record.
     logger.info(f"DB update on record: f{record}")
     # Handle the update here

db_listener.listen_and_call(callback_method)
```

### How to use this

#### 1. Add a Trigger to a model in the database

This is very easy. Just add the mixin TriggerModelMixin to the model that you want to add support to. This Mixin will handle the creation of the triggers, and the Listening method to notify when the triggers are called.

[image: Example of adding trigger support to a model]

#### 2. Create a ListenThread to have a Callback

We have two modes for the listener: `async` (non-blocking) and `sync` (blocking). By default, it will be `non-blocking`, you can change this with the `sync=True` if you want it to be blocking.

To use it (in either case), create a callback method. Note that this callback method will be blocking when updates are received (records are processed in serial), so do not have heavy load or I/O in this method. The only requirement of this method is a keyed parameter of `record` - which will be where the record from the database is returned as a dictionary.

From this, just create the listener, then call `listen_and_call`.

[image: Example of adding a callback method and registering it with the trigger.]